# Passing values from keyvault to json file for azure search deployment

Tags: azure, continuous-deployment

I am trying to setup a azure search pipeline and deploy everything from my dev to test space. The json files under datasources folder require connection strings for the DB, but I don't know how I can reference a keyvault item into those json files so that connection string data is passed safely. [file that needs reference to the keyvault item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2snAv.png)

Is it even possible to directly reference a keyvault item within the json files in the pipeline? Is there a way I can reference a variable in the .yml files in pipelines that saves the keyvault item and then place it where the connection string is required?

Comment: anyone can help me with this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.